# Enable ssl connection between bitbucket server and aws rds oracle database giving error

Tags: oracle, ssl, amazon-rds, bitbucket-server

I am trying to establish ssl connection between bitbucket server(hosted on EC2 instance) and AWS RDS oracle database giving error. when i try to establish the ssl connection using openssl from bitbucket server to db. ssl connection is established and comes fine. but when i try to add the changes in bitbucker.properties file for the same. i am getting different errors and bitbucket server not coming up after restart. my bitbucket.properties file looks like:

```
jdbc.driver=org.oracle.Driver
jdbc.url=<url>:8442/ORACLE
jdbc.user=bitbucketuser
jdbc.password=****
server.port=8442                
server.secure=true
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.protocol=TLSv1.2
server.ssl.key-store="path/to/my/keystorepath"
server.ssl.key-store-password="mypassword"
server.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
server.ssl.keystore-type=JKS
```

prior to this, i have created the options for ssl enable at port 8442 and attached it to option group. restarted db to reflect the changes. i also followed the following document to add the certificate in to my bitbucket path. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/ssl-certificate-rotation-oracle.html.

can anyone help me to provide the properties file structure/details for enabling the ssl from bitbucket server to oracle rds or guide me with the steps for ssl establish between bitbucket server to rds db?

Much appreciated!!!

Comment: The doesn't look like a proper JDBC connect string. The port number is wrong, and Oracle DB does not natively support TLS. Your "server" properties are for Tomcat, not Oracle. See here for examples of connecting to Oracle on AWS: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToOracleInstance.html

Comment: thanks for your assistance. 1.jdbc connection string is still the same as previously( working ild setup with ssl) 2. port no i use 8442 (i have used the same in option group for oracle db) i think we can use any port no. correct me if iam wrong. 3. "Your "server" properties are for Tomcat, not Oracle" - can you elabrate it? if i am using it for tomcat, can you please give the setting for oracle? thanks a lot.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the error you're getting. Do any relevant stack traces or exceptions appear in `$BITBUCKET_HOME/logs/atlassian-bitbucket.log` on startup?